# Ansible Tower and Ansible Version

Tags: ansible

I have Ansible Tower Version of 2.4.5 and ansible version 2.1.1.

I wanted to Update Tower Version to 3.0.0 as [Official Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/installandreference/upgrade_tower.html) says

Does anyone know if Updating Tower Version will require Ansible Version update too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you question you link to the latest version documentation, as per today you must upgrade the version of **Ansible to 2.2 (at minimum)** required to run **Ansible Tower versions 3.2 and later**.

In you case, you want to upgrade to the version **3.0.0**:

You may refer to the [Ansible Tower 3.0 Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.0/html/upgrade-migration-guide/upgrade_considerations.html).

In the [Requirements documentation for version 3.0.0](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.0/html/installandreference/requirements_refguide.html#ansible-software-requirements) it says:

> While Ansible Tower depends on Ansible Playbooks and requires the
>   installation of the latest stable version of Ansible before installing
>   Tower, manual installations of Ansible are no longer required.
>
> Beginning with Ansible Tower version 2.3, the Tower installation
>   program attempts to install Ansible as part of the installation
>   process. Previously, Tower required manual installations of the
>   Ansible software release package before running the Tower installation
>   program. Now, Tower attempts to install the latest stable Ansible
>   release package.
>
> If performing a bundled tower installation, the installation program
>   attempts to install Ansible (and its dependencies) from the bundle for
>   you (refer to Using the Bundled Tower Installation Program for more
>   information).
>
> If you choose to install Ansible on your own, the Tower installation
>   program will detect that Ansible has been installed and will not
>   attempt to reinstall it. **Note that you must install Ansible using a
>   package manager like yum and that the latest stable version must be
>   installed for Ansible Tower to work properly.**